# RXJS Error for Internet Disconnection

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

Using Angular 2 I have an HTTP API where through RXJS I'm trying to implement retrywhen to retry the API when there is an internet disconnection. What I need to know is what the error status code for when is internet disconnection. So far I have:

```
this.http.get("http://www.someapifunction.com/api" , {headers: headers, params: data})
    .retryWhen(error => {
                   return error
                      .flatMap((error: any) => {
                         if(error.status  === ?????) {
                           return Observable.of(error.status).delay(1000)
                         }
                    return Observable.throw({error: 'No retry'});
       })
      .take(5)

     });
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => { 
          console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('error',err);
        this.showError(err);  
      },
      () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You should include the code that initiates the request. Or at least explain what it is you are using to do so. However, regardless of whatever is used, there's unlikely to be a `status` as that's something that's returned by the server - from which you've been disconnected.

Comment: Sure I have updated the details. Also the server does return disconnected because you can't talk to the server in the first place for it to give you a response. So I am after is how to catch disconnection errors

Comment: If you're using Chrome, just use the DevTools to go offline and see what the thrown error instance is.

Comment: That is the thing there is no error code for disconnection just only Failed to load resource: The Internet connection appears to be offline.

Comment: If you don't have an internet connection, I'd expect the `status` to be zero: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.1/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L235-L242

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Comment: Or you could just read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

Comment: Or you could just read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details